# How does one create an RSS feed which reads posts with tag1 OR tag2?

Tags: feature-request, rss

I would like to subscribe to an RSS feed for posts which are tagged as subjects I like.

For example, the feed https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/galois-theory+field-theory will read posts that bear both tags 'galois-theory' and 'field-theory' (this is what the + accomplishes); what I want is to read posts which are tagged with one or the other.

Comment: A not entirely satisfactory work around is to subscribe separately to the galois-theory and field-theory tags; the downside is that you get duplicate postings.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out that one can do this by replacing + in the link above with +or+. For example, `http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/galois-theory+or+field-theory`