# Notification after a downvoted answer was edited

Tags: discussion, feature-request, down-votes, notifications

Is there an option to receive a notification, when a post you downvoted was edited?
With a downvote you suggest that something is wrong, after the poster edited it, maybe there is no reason anymore for the downvote.

Comment: You can favor it...

Comment: If you haven't seen one, then there probably isn't. This would make a good [meta-tag:feature-request].

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165962/158524

Comment: this would need to be optional...

Comment: SE should introduce a Watch list in addition to Favorites list. A single favorite star can't do both things: mark the questions to which user hopes to return (to write or improve an answer), and mark the questions that are simply monitored in case something happens to them. // The Watch list should be visible *to the user only*, unlike the Favorites which are public. Otherwise, adding downvoted questions to the list would compromise the anonymity of votes. // Of course, such requests were made [already](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13066/) and of course to no avail.

Comment: So here is a workaround. In order to watch a post for future changes, you can leave a comment containing invisible LaTeX `${}$` (of course, the comment should be a real comment, e.g., a remark about what's wrong). Later (some weeks later), run [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/101023) which displays the posts to which you commented with this string, and which were edited **after your comment**. The results are ordered by the last edit date. (Note: it is best to log in to Data Explorer to run the query, so that UserID field gets pre-filled with your user id.)

Comment: @5pm: Now that’s potentially useful even to those of us who never downvote but do leave comments in hopes of getting mistakes corrected. I don’t know how often it happens, but if the poster corrects the answer without responding to the comment, I don’t normally see it.

Comment: It's easy to forget to insert the `${}$` code, but one can   include it in the auto-comments inserted by the customizable [auto-comment script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se).

Comment: This would also be useful in other stackexchange sections, in particular those not allowing LaTeX...

Comment: If you support this, you should upvote the respective [Allow me to get notifications on specific down-voted questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165962/146482) @cardinal linked to - this is something not specific to math.SE but the whole SE network

Comment: Huh, this is perfect and I need it!

Answer (score 5):

If you are willing to get a somewhat enlarged range of notifications, you can subscribe to the RSS feed for that Question (this will notify you not only of edits to the Question, but new & edited Answers; however Comment activity does not appear to trigger notification).  You'll need an RSS client, such as Google Reader, to receive such a feed.

Even more complicated/general notifications were mentioned [in this meta Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6268/3111).

Comment: Side note: Google has just announced that it will cease operations of Google Reader on July 1.